# Proving a set of sequences is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $(a_n)_{(n \geq 0)} $ of all real numbers satisfying:
>
> $$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n$$ for all $n \geq 0$
>
> Show $S$ is a vector space (using the axioms that define a vector space). Firstly show that the sum of 2 sequences and the scalar multiple of a sequence is in $S$.

I'm having trouble deciding whether or not my proof is sufficient, because it seems too obvious:

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two real numbers, then $$a_{n+2} + b_{n+2} = (a_{n+1} + b_{n+1}) + (a_n + b_n) $$ Which is another sequence. You can employ the same argument for the scalar multiple case, by introducing a scalar $c$ and creating a new sequence with $c*a_n$.

Now we have to check if $S$ is a vector space:

1. Commutativity of addition: $a_n + b_n = b_n + a_n$ for every real number, so S  is associative.
2. Associativity of addition: $(a_n +b_n) + c_n = a_n + (b_n + c_n)$ for every real number, so S is commutative.
3. Identity element of addition: If $a_n=0$, then the entire sequence is zero and since $b_n +0 = b_n$ for every real number, there exists an idetity element of additon.
4. Inverse element of addition: Since $a_n + (- a_n) =0$ for every real number, there exists an inverse element of addition.
5. Associative scalar multiplication: Since $b*c*(a_n)= b*(c*a_n)$ for every real number, scalar multplication is associative.
6. Identity element of scalar multiplication: (argument similar to 3)

7, 8. Similar to 5, etc.

So I have a feeling I'm oversimplifying:

- Is it enough to do the algebra with just $a_n$ or do you need to perform it with $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n$.
- Is this way of proving (regardless of the answer to the question above) sound, or is it too shallow or even incorrect?

Comment: Your verification is correct.